# Magento 2 get categories by store Query

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to get all enable categories for specific store from query in Magento 2 database. As I tried from database query from table `catalog_category_entity_int`

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_entity_int` WHERE `attribute_id`=46 AND `store_id`=1 GROUP BY `entity_id`
```

Where **46** is attribute id for enable attribute.

With this query i am getting all categories ids but for all stores categories are same if i change **store_id** the results are same for all stores but I need store specific categories as I am seeing in magento admin **catalog > Category** section.

Answer (score 0):

Use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface for current store and apply it in your query

Try this

```
protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    $data = []
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($data);
}

$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setStore($this->storeManager->getStore());

foreach ($categories as $category){
    $category->getId();
}
```

Comment: I asked from query not programmatically.